# How to clear ionic local storage data after 24 hours?

Tags: typescript, angular7, ionic4

I'm creating ionic 4 angular app , and using ionic local storage to store some item . i want to clear local storage data after 24 hr .it is possible or not ?

[Here is the ionic storage docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what your real aim is.

If you want the data to be auto-wiped for some kind of security reasons then I don't think so.

If you just want to prevent the user accessing old data you need to store the start datetime, then the next time you try to access the data, check if its over 24hrs and then wipe the database if so.